# Disable native library for some Android version in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

So, basically, I'm trying to use react-native-webrtc and it's required to have minSdk 24 to use this library. I'm not really experienced in Android, so question is can you make this library "optional"? Like if your phone doesn't support it, just ignore it?
I can't provide any code, since I don't really know where to start digging, so any tips could help.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createEgl14([I)Lorg/webrtc/EglBase14; in class Lorg/webrtc/EglBase; or its super classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use:

```
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform.desugaring=false
```

in a gradle.propeties file. Seems like a workaround for now, but it's the only solution I found for now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's optional, it would probably break your code.

You can change the MinSdk version of your project on the file: `Android/build.gradle`
The SDK version you put there, it's the minimum version your app will be disponibilized by google play to be installed.

So if The MinSdk number of the dependencies of your project it's smaller than your project MinSdk version, it will throw an error when compiling.

You can solve that by changing the MinSdk on the file: `node_modules/react-native-webrtc/Android/build.gradle`

Maybe you want to fork the [react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) project on github, and then changing the MinSdk, and then: `npm install --save YourGithubForkHere`

If you manage to get it optional, you can check the Android version by using:

```js
import {Platform} from 'react-native'

[...]

if(Platform.OS == 'android' && Platform.Version >= 21){
  //Do Something
}
[...]
```

[here](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) you can check the SDK number of all the android versions.

[Edit]

About the error code you provided: As said [here](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/issues/720) the problem is with the `minSdk` version being `24` instead of `21`

But as seen on the [Android/build.gradle](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/android/build.gradle) the `minSdkVersion` is `16`, so you can fix your problem by running:

> npm install --save https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc

if you use npm

or if you use yarn:

> yarn add https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc

Then recompile your project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The library is actually getting build, but it crashes right away on 23 SDK version. So the needed changes will have to be done in native Java code?

Comment: You can provide the error of the crash? if there's no error returned, you can get by using `adb shell -x logcat`, saving it fo a file, and then search for  "beginning of crash" or something like this, it will return the error

Comment: I fixed it different way but you made me go in the right direction